# catching the error when item can't be found in textfile

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, error-handling, text-files

I have a list, btc.txt, with all of the dates from sometime in 2013 to today and the average price of BTC for that day. Here are the contents of the textfile:

```
Date,Price
...
"Jun 06, 2018",7639.970
"Jun 05, 2018",7567.330
"Jun 04, 2018",7618.500
"Jun 03, 2018",7676.170
"Jun 02, 2018",7590.080
"Jun 01, 2018",7521.070
...
```

I have a list of dates, and in my code, I am looking for the corresponding date in the btc.txt and finding the average price of BTC for that date:

```
df = pd.read_csv("btc.txt")
dates = [..., "May 23, 2017", "Jun 04, 2018", "Oct 4, 2018", ...]

initial_p = []
for item in dates:
    if(item != "N/A"):
        if(df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"].values[0]):
            price = df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"].values[0]
            print(price)
            initial_p.append(price)
        else:
            num = int(item[len(item)-1])
            num -= 1
            item[len(item)-1] = num
            price = (df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"].values[0])
            initial_p.append(price)

    else:
        initial_p.append(item)
```

As you can see, there are dates in my list that don't exist, like October 4, 2018. Because it doesn't exist in btc.txt, I get this following error when it gets to that date that doesn't exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getICOdate.py", line 173, in <module>
    initial_price("btc.txt")
  File "getICOdate.py", line 159, in initial_price
    if(df[df["Date"] == item]["Price"].values[0]):
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I tried to catch the error by putting an if statement on line 6 of my code as you can see above but it didn't work. Basically what I want to do in my code is that if that date can't be found in btc.txt, the date will be modified to a year back and searched again (so "Oct 04, 2018" will be changed to "Oct 04, 2017")

Comment: What is "df" in your program?

Comment: Assuming `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame`, you could do `if item in df.Date.values:`.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille df = pd.read_csv("btc.txt")

Comment: Dit you try @Jeronimo's suggestion?

Comment: @Jeronimo it worked, thank you!